# Is it possible to use internal load balancer with backend on App Engine Flexible instances?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, app-engine-flexible

We need this to use non standard TCP port. From what I can see Load balancers need instance groups to be defined, and instance groups are compute engine thing. So I wonder if it's possible at all.

Comment: You are trying to mix 2 worlds initially design to not work together: Serverless and IaaS. App Engine Flexible is a strange stuff that use subnet but you don't see your VM on the Compute Engine page. You can access to your VPC, firewall rules and so on. It's a very special stuff, and trying to do strange things with a special stuff is hard and I'm not sure of the reliability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine is a managed service, this means that it has it's own load balancer and manages the requests in a very specific way which you can check over [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-requests-are-handled).

As mentioned by @guillaume blaquiere, you would be mixing 2 concepts completely different which are IaaS and PaaS. If you need to set up a specific load balancer with certain behaviour for your App to run, you may be better off using Managed instance groups rather than App Engine so you have more control on everything rather than relying on GCP's management.

I hope you find this information useful.

Comment: What you and Guillaume write make total sense, so thanks a lot. And actually we would never go this way, custom port forwarding and network configuration (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#network_settings) confused us so much.